# DXA 1.2 Custom DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1.dll

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.2

I have just gone to modify the DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1 code for a DXA 1.2 website to implement the [DXA Preview Alchemy Extension](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/alchemy-plugin-dxa-page-preview) for 2013 SP1 but the source code that is in [Github](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1) does not match the source code when I decompile the DLL that is provided with DXA in _references\dd4t-2.0-dxa\

Is it customised? Can that code be provided if it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXA 1.2 did use a custom build of DD4T 2.0 because at release time there was no public DD4T 2.0 release available (only beta builds).

The code differences are available in the forks on the SDL GitHub account, which are only the https://github.com/sdl/DD4T.TridionTemplates and https://github.com/sdl/DD4T.Model repositories, there were no code changes in the `DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1` so you should be able to find that back via its version tag, it should match the https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2013sp1/releases/tag/2.0.5-beta release

Comment: Thanks Bart. I was using the 2.0.8 release code and not 2.0.5-beta